# Python equivalent for sprintf

Tags: python, hash, directory

Does someone have a nice tip how to port tis PHP function to python?

```
/**
 * converts id (media id) to the corresponding folder in the data-storage
 * eg: default mp3 file with id 120105 is stored in
 * /(storage root)/12/105/default.mp3
 * if absolute paths are needed give path for $base
 */

public static function id_to_location($id, $base = FALSE)
{
    $idl = sprintf("%012s",$id);
    return $base . (int)substr ($idl,0,4) . '/'. (int)substr($idl,4,4) . '/' . (int)substr ($idl,8,4);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In one line, (Python 2.x):

```
id_to_location = lambda i: '/%d/%d/%d/' % (int(i)/1e8, int(i)%1e8/1e4, int(i)%1e4)
```

then:

```
print id_to_location('001200230004')
'/12/23/4/'
```

Answer (score 6):

For python 2.x, you have these options:

**[best option]** The newer [str.format](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) and the full [format specification](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#formatspec), e.g.

```
"I like {food}".format(food="chocolate")
```

The older [interpolation formatting](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations) syntax e.g.

```
"I like %s" % "berries"
"I like %(food)s" % {"food": "cheese"}
```

[string.Template](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#template-strings), e.g.

```
string.Template('I like $food').substitute(food="spinach")
```

Answer (score 3):

You want to use the format() method for strings in Python 3:

http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#formatstrings

or check the string interpolation documentation for Python 2.X

http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html

Answer (score 2):

Ok - found a way - not so nice I think but does the job...

```
def id_to_location(id):
    l = "%012d" % id
    return '/%d/%d/%d/' % (int(l[0:4]), int(l[4:8]), int(l[8:12]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can bring in the base with a default parameter. Perhaps you want it like this:

```
def id_to_location(id,base=""):
   l = "%012d" % id
   return '%s/%d/%d/%d/' % (base,int(l[0:4]), int(l[4:8]), int(l[8:12]))
```